# Wrong number of data blocks given by stats command

Tags: gnuplot

I am using the following Gnuplot script with Gnuplot version 4.6 patchlevel 5 :

```
##### Prologue #####
clear # erases the current screen or output device 
reset # all graph-related options take on their default values

###### Plot options #####
set style data lines
set surface
set dgrid3d 64,64 qnorm 2
set hidden3d
set ticslevel 0.8
set isosample 40,40

set view 60, 30, 1, 1
set contour base

######  Plot data   #####
stats 'modele.out'
do for [i=0:int(STATS_blocks-1)] {
    set key title 'density at t'.i
    splot 'modele.out' every :::i::i using 2:3:5 notitle
    pause 0.5
}
```

and the following file :

```
# Time is  0.000000000000000E+000
0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.9787    0.0213
0.0000    0.0000    0.3333    0.9077    0.0923
0.0000    0.0000    0.6667    0.9738    0.0262
0.0000    0.0000    1.0000    0.9673    0.0327
0.0000    0.3333    0.0000    0.9044    0.0956
0.0000    0.3333    0.3333    0.9246    0.0754
0.0000    0.3333    0.6667    0.9181    0.0819
0.0000    0.3333    1.0000    0.9089    0.0911
0.0000    0.6667    0.0000    0.9348    0.0652
0.0000    0.6667    0.3333    0.9372    0.0628
0.0000    0.6667    0.6667    0.9933    0.0067
0.0000    0.6667    1.0000    0.9273    0.0727
0.0000    1.0000    0.0000    0.9909    0.0091
0.0000    1.0000    0.3333    0.9771    0.0229
0.0000    1.0000    0.6667    0.9014    0.0986
0.0000    1.0000    1.0000    0.9312    0.0688

# Time is   50.0000000000000     
50.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.1036    0.8370
50.0000    0.0000    0.3333    0.1036    0.9093
50.0000    0.0000    0.6667    0.1031    0.9368
50.0000    0.0000    1.0000    0.1042    0.8378
50.0000    0.3333    0.0000    0.1034    0.9556
50.0000    0.3333    0.3333    0.1039    0.9127
50.0000    0.3333    0.6667    0.1041    0.9761
50.0000    0.3333    1.0000    0.1041    0.9587
50.0000    0.6667    0.0000    0.1033    0.9432
50.0000    0.6667    0.3333    0.1043    0.9503
50.0000    0.6667    0.6667    0.1087    0.5931
50.0000    0.6667    1.0000    0.1057    0.9579
50.0000    1.0000    0.0000    0.1044    0.8390
50.0000    1.0000    0.3333    0.1046    0.9101
50.0000    1.0000    0.6667    0.1062    0.9597
50.0000    1.0000    1.0000    0.1063    0.8494

# Time is   100.000000000000     
100.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0997    0.8433
100.0000    0.0000    0.3333    0.0998    0.9123
100.0000    0.0000    0.6667    0.0995    0.9501
100.0000    0.0000    1.0000    0.0999    0.8442
100.0000    0.3333    0.0000    0.0999    0.9593
100.0000    0.3333    0.3333    0.1000    0.9157
100.0000    0.3333    0.6667    0.1000    0.9794
100.0000    0.3333    1.0000    0.1002    0.9612
100.0000    0.6667    0.0000    0.0997    0.9534
100.0000    0.6667    0.3333    0.1000    0.9542
100.0000    0.6667    0.6667    0.1001    0.6028
100.0000    0.6667    1.0000    0.1004    0.9584
100.0000    1.0000    0.0000    0.1000    0.8448
100.0000    1.0000    0.3333    0.1002    0.9143
100.0000    1.0000    0.6667    0.1005    0.9571
100.0000    1.0000    1.0000    0.1006    0.8490
```

I don't understand why the stats command returns that I have only 1 data block. That should be 3 in my opinion. Is the file badly formatted ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`stats` gives you the number of *indexable* blocks in your data file. These blocks are separated by **pairs** of blank records (i.e. **two** blank lines).

If you did `plot 'modele.out' index 0`  you would find that it plotted all your data points as well, whereas `index 1` would give you an error. There is only one (indexable) block in your data.

#### The solution

- separate your blocks by two blank lines
- change your `splot` command to `splot 'modele.out' index i using 2:3:5 notitle`

---

When you are using `splot`, a single blank line separates each row (or *datablock*, to use the term in the manual). This isn't the same thing as a block! In all other contexts (as far as I'm aware) there are two lines between each block (or *indexable block* to use the term in the manual).

---

#### update

As suggested by Christoph in the comments, if you wanted to keep your file in the same format and were sure that there were no blank lines at the end, you could change your loop to this:

```
do for [i=0:STATS_blank] {
```

and use your original `splot` line (with `every`, rather than `index`).

Comment: Thanks Tom. Is there a difference between a block and an indexable block ? I usually have no problem with blocks separated by only one line.

Comment: @bela83 no problem. I've added some explanation to my answer. Hopefully that clears things up.

Comment: Great ! Now I use two blank lines to separate the blocks but I encounter the following issue : `line 29: warning: Cannot contour non grid data. Please use "set dgrid3d"` I don't understand since this command is in my script already.

Comment: @bela83 I'm not 100% sure but I think that you should be using `splot 'modele.out' index i using 2:3:5 notitle` now.

Comment: It works now. There is still a `warning: No usable data in this plot to auto-scale axis range` but I will try to figure it out myself. Thanks !

Comment: @bela83 That's strange, if I add the blank lines and use the command above I don't get any error. Happy to help anyway.

Comment: Solved. This was due to two extraneous blank lines at the end of the file ! Thanks again.

Comment: @bela83 Good, I'm glad your problem is solved. If you are happy with my answer, don't forget to accept it :)

Comment: If you are sure that you don't have any trailing blank lines, you can use `STATS_blank` as iteration number.